# Layout pushing down content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-tabs

[image]Not sure what is going on in my layout but after the tabs, the content starts halfway down the screen...

These are the layouts in order from parent to child

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Prof">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/tabs_profile" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


tabs profile layout:

<!-- for Tabs -->
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorTabs"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/tabsTxtColor"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />


    <include layout="@layout/content_profile" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


content xml layout:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="click THIS"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textColor="@color/tabsTxtColor"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</RelativeLayout>


fragment layout:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:id="@+id/productDefaultPicture"
            android:src="@drawable/default_product"
            android:layout_above="@+id/hashes"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/previousPicture"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_circled_left_48"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/nextPicture"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_circled_right_48"/>


        <View
            android:background="#16000000"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/break2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/productDefaultPicture"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/hashes"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_dark_material_dark"
        android:text="iPhone 6"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'hashes' (id) view is anchored to the bottom of the `RelativeLayout`, which fills the fragment.

It looks like everything else is positioned above the hashes view, so it is all anchored to the bottom of the fragment.

You can try and position things relative to the center or top of the `RelativeLayout`.